# A problem of olympiad.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math

This nice functional equation was proposed in the “VIII Olimpíada Iberoamericana de Matemáticas” held in Mexico (1993).

> Find all the functions  $f:\mathbb N^* \to \mathbb N^*$ such that
>
> i) If $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$
>
> ii) $f(yf(x))=x^2f(xy)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb N^*$

The solution given in a book edited by the OEI (Organization of Iberoamerican States) is $f(x)=x^2$. However this function does not satisfy condition i) for negative numbers, so the solution must be conditioned in any way (it is possible!) or should change $\mathbb N^*$ by $\mathbb N^+$.

**►►►I translate here the solution given in the book. I do this in attention to a comment of @Cyclone.**

We have $$a)\space f(xf(x))=x^2f(x^2) \\b)\space f(f(x))=x^2f(x)\Rightarrow f(f(x^2))=x^4f(x^2)\\ c)\space f(f(x)\cdot f(x))=x^2f(xf(x))=x^4f(x^2)$$
From b) and c) it follows $$f(f(x^2))=f([f(x^2)])$$ hence $$f(x^2)=[f(x)]^2$$ and because of the condition i) $f$ is injective.

We’ll prove that $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb N^*$.

If $$f(x)<x^2, f(f(x))<f(x^2)=[f(x)]^2\Rightarrow x^2f(x)<[f(x)]^2\Rightarrow x^2< f(x)$$ which is absurd.

If  $$f(x)>x^2, f(f(x))>f(x^2)=[f(x)]^2\Rightarrow x^2f(x)>[f(x)]^2\Rightarrow x^2> f(x)$$ which is absurd too.

Thus, $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb N^*$, and this function satisfy the  statement of the problem.

**NOTE.-This answer don’t add anything about the uniqueness of the solution.**

Comment: $f(x) = x^{2}$?

Comment: It seems like $f(x)=x^2$. Necessarily $f(1)=1$.

Comment: There are no negative numbers in $\mathbb N^*$. Perhaps you are thinking of $\mathbb Z^*$?

Comment: $\mathbb N^*$ is the set of **positive integers**. Are you confusing $\mathbb Z^*$ with $\mathbb N^*$ ?

Comment: I have seen a lot of times in many books and papers puting asterisk in $\mathbb N$ as meaning $\mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: @user26857: Thanks for your edition.

Comment: Piquito, I'd be interested to see the solution to the problem. Could you post it here?

Comment: @Cyclone: with pleasure. Wait just the time I fight against English and Tex Command.( I am not mexican; these Olympics are celebrated in Spain all countries speaking Spanish in the american continent. That year 1993 was in Mexico).

Comment: @Cyclone: Sorry. I see now that I cannot write an answer, maybe because this question is in hold. If you want, I can send you by mail where you indicated to me. Regards.

Comment: @Cyclone: I give you the answer of the book in the edition I am going to make before the question be deletted. You are welcome.

Comment: Hi @Cyclone. I have written the answer of the book editing it in the same question. Tell me if  you don't understand it?

Comment: If f(x) is not positive function, inequality $x<y f(x)<(y)$ is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x=0$, $f(xf(0))=0$.
When we put $f(0)=k,f(kx)=0.$So , $f(x)=0$ or $f(0)=k=0.$

put $y=\frac1x$,$f(\frac{f(x)}x)=x^2f(1)$

if put $f(x)=ax^2+bx$

$a(ax+b)^2+b(ax+b)=x^2f(1)=x^2(a+b)$

$⇔a^3x^2+(2a^2b+ab)x+ab^2+b^2=x^2(a+b)$

$⇒b^2(a+1)=0$
,
$ab(2a+1)=0$
,
$a^3=a+b$

$⇒b=0 , a=±1,0$

therefore by $f:\mathbb N^* \to \mathbb N^*$

$f(x)=x^2$

Comment: Dear friend: the symbol $\mathbb N^*$ means $x\ne 0$. Besides $f(x)=0$ does not satisfy condition i). However I see  that the function $f(x)=x^2$ wich figures as correct in my source of the problem, does not satisfy condition i) for negative numbers.Try to edit your answer, please.Regards.